# Converting a Swift UnsafePointer<AudioStreamBasicDescription> to a Dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, swift2

I want to know how to create a dictionary of `[String:AnyObject]` from an  `UnsafePointer<AudioStreamBasicDescription>`

I guess I don't understand how to work with an `UnsafePointer<T>` in `Swift`. Here's where I'm starting from - The `AVAudioFile` class has a `fileFormat` property which is of `AVAudioFormat` Type. `AVAudioFormat` has a `streamDescription` property which returns an `UnsafePointer<AudioStreamBasicDescription>` as a read-only property.

I'd like to see what the values are in this struct and converting to a Dictionary seems like it might be reasonable goal. In fact, there already seems to be a "settings" property on the `AVAudioFormat` Class that does this but I'm interested in understanding the "right way" to access the values stored in the `UnsafePointer` myself.

From the docs

`Discussion: Returns the AudioStreamBasicDescription (ASBD) struct, for use with lower-level audio APIs`

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioFormat_Class/index.html

Is there a way to do an unsafe conversion after checking if the struct is not nil? Would I use an unsafeBitCast here? I'm hesitant to jump into this too much as I've read that it's "extremely dangerous"...

I realize I can access the underlying memory with the following:

```
let audioFileURL:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("FILENAME", with Extension: "mp3")
var file:AVAudioFile?
do {
  file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: audioFileURL)
  guard let file = file else {
    fatalError("file must not be nil")
  }
}catch {
  print(error)
}

let format = file.processingFormat
let asbd:AudioStreamBasicDescription = format.streamDescription.memory
```

Is that dangerous and would I need to dealloc for some reason after creating the asbd constant?

I've tried to follow along with the post here http://sitepoint.com/using-legacy-c-apis-swift but I'm just not getting it... Looking for any direction on best practices here.

### Update:

Doing a bit more research, it seems that it might be possible to create the dictionary using reflect based off this post: http://freecake.angelodipaolo.org/simple-reflection-in-swift/

Here's what I have so far:

```
let asbdMirror = reflect(asbd)
var asbdDict = [String: Any]()
for i in 0..<asbdMirror.count {
  let (propertyName, childMirror) = asbdMirror[i]
  asbdDict[propertyName] = childMirror.value
}
```

Any reason this is a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything correctly, you can access all the values in the description with `asbd.mSampleRate` and such. It wouldn't make sense to convert it to a dictionary because that's just not what it is, there are no keys for the values.

You also don't have to dealloc anything when working with pointers like this unless you allocate one yourself (when using `malloc` or `alloc`)

Comment: The only reason I was thinking of converting to a dictionary is so that I could do a loop through and print out each property's value. Is there a way to iterate over all of the properties in a struct?

Comment: @JustinLeviWinter No there's not, but there aren't too many values anyways, structs aren't made to store an array of values and loop through them

Comment: Doing a bit more research, it seems that it might be possible to create the dictionary using reflect - see edit above.

Comment: @JustinLeviWinter Reflection should only be used in situations where everything else has been tried and there really isn't any other way. Especially in Swift, because Swift is all about static stuff, reflection on the other hand is purely dynamic. Reflection code is also slower, more unreadable and not very nice to work with. Also reflection can't really do all that much in Swift anyways

Comment: Fair enough. Appreciate the feedback. Thanks for your help. Awarding the answer to you.