# Pointer dereferencing Swift

Tags: swift, pointers, dereference

In `C` & `Objective C`, we used to dereference a pointer and get the value as follows:

```
  p->a = 1
  or int x = p->a
```

But I can't find an equivalent in Swift. I have a return type `UnsafePointer`  to `AudioStreamBasicDescription?` whose member values I need to read.

Comment: Just access the struct members by name with a `.`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439906/converting-a-swift-unsafepointeraudiostreambasicdescription-to-a-dictionary

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use the `pointee` property on your [UnsafePointer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafepointer) to access the memory it points to. So your C example would read as `let x = p.pointee.a`.